# Grouping SQL results from a Union

Tags: sql, group-by, union

I have a table in my database used for users to follow eachother.

The table goes as follows:

```
UniqueID
FollowerID
FollowedUserID
```

FollowID is the UserID of the person who is following someone else.

FollowedUserID is the UserID of the person who is being followed by the FollowID User.

I'd like to retrieve a list of connections from this table based off a single user. My query should return all the other UserIDs that the current user is **either following or being followed by** with no overlaps.

So say we have a few entries here:

```
FollowerID   FollowedUserID
    1              2
    1              3
    4              1
    2              1
```

This would show that the User **1** is following users 2 and 3, and thus users 2 and 3 are being followed by user **1**. On the other side of the spectrum it shows that User **1** is followed by users 2 and 3.

What I'd like to do is find out the connections that user **1** has, so the query should return users: 2, 3, and 4 (user **1** is following users 2 and 3 and is being followed by user 4)

How can I achieve this from a single query?

A **connection** is considered either being followed or following someone else, so it is possible that some duplicate results can occur (if both users are following eachother). I'd like to be able to group these results so that the result is distinct.

I've tried a UNION query similar to:

```
SELECT FollowerID, FollowedUserID From Follows WHERE FollowerID = 1
UNION
SELECT FollowerID, FollowedUserID FROM Follows WHERE FollowedUserID = 1
```

Theoretically I'd like to Group FollowerID and FollowedUserID together to keep them distinct.

I'm not interested in retrieving a non-distinct result and then creating a dataset of unique results php side -- the query should return distinct values only.

Comment: What RDBMS is this? Is this MS SQL Server?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is. What is wrong with the UNION query you posted? And what do you mean by "Group FollowerID and FollowedUserID together to keep them distinct"? That does not make sense. Maybe you could add the result you want to get, then maybe we can find a query to produce it.

Comment: And BTW, `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` will automatically only retrieve distinct values. If you want duplicates, you must use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I guess I misphrased my question -- by duplicates i mean a symmetrical listing, if one entry is [2,1] and another is [1,2], i want to have one result (**2**) -- user 1 is following user 2, and user 2 is following user 1. A connection exists when one or the other happens, so all I care about is a single instance of these 2 results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close, but you have to reverse the order of the columns in one of the branches of the UNION:

```
SELECT FollowerID AS reference_user, FollowedUserID AS connection
  FROM Follows
 WHERE FollowerID = 1
UNION
SELECT FollowedUserID AS reference_user, FollowerID AS connection
  FROM Follows
 WHERE FollowedUserID = 1
GROUP BY reference_user;
```

Note that if you drop the WHERE clauses, you get all connections for everyone.

Comment: Thanks @Jon -- The Group By will group the entire union? And thanks for the note, I do realize that, if I do need to look at all connections I'll do that

Comment: @Atticus: yes, the GROUP BY applies to the whole query.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd need to revise your query:

```
edit: removed the un-needed select distinct
SELECT FollowedUserID as ID From Follows WHERE FollowerID = 1
UNION
SELECT FollowerID as ID FROM Follows WHERE FollowedUserID = 1
```

But that doesn't quite answer the question of direction.

```
SELECT FollowedUserID as ID, "follow" as direction 
From Follows 
WHERE FollowerID = 1
UNION
SELECT FollowerID as ID, "followed" as direction 
FROM Follows 
WHERE FollowedUserID = 1
```

Now you know the direction of the connection as well.

Comment: Since you wrote UNION and not UNION ALL, the outer DISTINCT is redundant - the UNION eliminates duplicates automatically.

Comment: The DISTINCT part is superfluous; UNION only returns distinct values anyway.

Comment: I knew that. Just forgot. I'm not sure I quite answer the question though. It looks like the op wants 1 query to answer two distinct questions and I'm not positive I (or you) retain enough information to know which way the connection goes. Then again, I don't think it is possible without a boolean marking the direction.  Hmmm, that is an idea.

Comment: Since one part of the question said that the desired answer was '2, 3, 4' for user 1, your first answer is sufficient.  Your second answer preserves the extra information, but would require two lines for user 2, one tagged 'follow' and one tagged 'followed'.